# Numpy : how to fill an array smartly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to create an 3D array in numpy as follow :

```
[ 0 1 0 1 0 1
  0 1 0 1 0 1
  0 1 0 1 0 1
  0 1 0 1 0 1
  0 1 0 1 0 1 ] ...
```

Is there a nice way to write it ?

Answer (score 7):

Using [`np.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1])
my_tiled_array = np.tile(a, (3, 3))
```

Result:

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

---

Edit:
As @DSM suggests in a comment, if you really want a 3D array -- which is not entirely clear to me from your code sample -- you can use:

```
my_3d_tiled_arr = np.tile(a, (3, 3, 3))
```

Result:

```
array([[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]])
```

Comment: Isn't that a 2D array?  (It's entirely possible -- probable, even -- that's what the OP is really looking for, of course.)

Comment: @DSM, thank you for your comment. I will add another example to (hopefully) cover all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 1-D array, (again, it's not clear exactly what you want), you could do something like:

```
np.mod(np.arange(10),2)
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

which could, of course, be reshaped if needed. But, I think bernie's answer is much better and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

@bernie's method is great. A faster way of achieving the same thing can be to move elements (virtually) around instead of copying a pair of `[0, 1]` a lot of times. You could do the following :

```
import numpy as np
A1 = np.concatenate([np.zeros(108), np.ones(108)]).reshape((2,108))
A2 = A1.transpose()
A3 = A2.reshape((6,6,6))
```

The first line initializes a bunch of zeros and ones and packs them into a `2x108` array. The second line barely makes it into a `108x2` array. Then, the last line re-slices the array so it is `6x6x6` and looks like what you are looking for.

The only thing to look out for is the number of elements. Say you want a final 3D array of `6x6x6`, like in my example, you multiply the length of all axis (which gives us 216), then divide by 2 (= 108). That number is the number of both ones and zeros, And the number used in the `.reshape((2, n))` function call.

The reason it is so fast is that initializing vectors of zeros or ones is really quick, faster than copying an arbitrary array. Then, moving elements, like what `.transpose()` and `.reshape()` do, barely changes the way the elements are referenced, instead of moving the elements themselves in memory.